# Regular Expression for credit card verification

Tags: regex

I need to verify a credit card (dummy - i'm not doing any transaction in real). The conditions are

1. It has to be between 10 and 16 digits.
2. Start with a digit 3 or 4
3. Only digits are allowed i mean [0-9].

I tried it and mine was [3-4][0-9]{10-16}. But it seems to be not yielding results.

Thank you in anticipation

Comment: What exactly are you anticipating?

Comment: @user653622: No I mean, you should actually state a question (with a question mark); it makes the posts a lot clearer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Should be:

```
^[34][0-9]{9,15}$
```

- Start and end anchors are important, or the regex might match only a part from the whole string (for example. 16 digits out of 20)
- `[34]` one of the characters. `[3-4]` is the same.
- `{9,15}` is the proper syntax. Note that `[34]` is the first digit, so you need to subtract one.

Some Examples: http://www.rubular.com/r/q61cPPYW7E

Comment: ...and `[0-9]` is the same as `\d`. ;-)

Comment: @Tomalak - Not in .Net or other Unicode-aware flavors. I'm playing it safe `:)`

Comment: @kobi: Of course it's the same as `[0-9]`, even in .NET and other Unicode-aware flavors. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx#character_classes Unicode-aware engines have a special expression to match digits in other scripts.

Comment: @Tomalak - Try this one: `Match digits = Regex.Match("123٤٥٦", @"\d+"); Console.WriteLine(digits.Value);` . It's also in the specs, of course: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx#DigitCharacter

Comment: @kobi Damn, you're right. I see, I have to let go of some traditions. I think that it is highly counter-productive to expand well-settled conventions beyond their original meanings, but obviously they did that.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to determine if the credit card number does more than just meet the format of the RegEx by using some more aggressive validation.

You could use the [Luhn algorithm](http://orb-of-knowledge.blogspot.com/2009/08/extremely-fast-luhn-function-for-c.html) to verify the number or even use further validation to tell you [what company the credit card number belongs to](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/validation/creditcardvalidator.aspx).